# ASP Dropdown list with options set to false

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, webforms, html-select

I have a dropdownlist of the form:

```
 <asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="holdTypeDDL" ID="holdTypeDDL"></asp:DropDownList>
```

and is filled onload in c# codebehind of an aspx page when !Page.isPostback via :

```
 holdTypeDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Empty, false.ToString()));
            holdTypeDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(HoldTypeType.Now.Description(), false.ToString()));
            holdTypeDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(HoldTypeType.AAHoldType.Description(), true.ToString()));
            holdTypeDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(HoldTypeType.AAAHoldType.Description(), true.ToString()));
            holdTypeDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(HoldTypeType.AAAAHoldType.Description(), false.ToString()));
```

I have noticed if one of the options of the select are selected that have a string value of False, it does not consider it selected. I.e. the selected index is 0 after postback. If an item with true is selected and value grabbed on postback, it works fine.

I cannot find any documentation as to why this is. Why does having a "False" string in the value of an option element make it not post back properly?

EDIT:

Renders in HTML as such:

```
<select class="holdTypeDDL" id="BodyContent_holdTypeDDL" name="ctl00$BodyContent$holdTypeDDL">
    <option value="False"></option>
    <option value="False">Now</option>
    <option value="True">AA Hold Type</option>
    <option value="True">AAA Hold Type</option>
    <option value="False">AAAA Hold Type</option>

</select>
```

Comment: How does it render in HTML?

Comment: If I select "Now" and post back, it shows selected index = 0. If I select AAAA hold type it shows selected index = 0. If I select AA Hold Type, it shows selected index = 2

Comment: Changing it to something other than False fixes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe values should be unique. Because you have multiple `True`, `False` values, when it marks it as selected, it takes the first one with that value as selected. Why are you using these values? You could use the same as the Text, or change the values like this:

```
holdTypeDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(string.Empty, false.ToString() + "0"));
holdTypeDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(HoldTypeType.Now.Description(), false.ToString() + "1"));
holdTypeDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(HoldTypeType.AAHoldType.Description(), true.ToString() + "2"));
holdTypeDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(HoldTypeType.AAAHoldType.Description(), true.ToString() + "3"));
holdTypeDDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(HoldTypeType.AAAAHoldType.Description(), false.ToString() + "4"));
```

That should work.

Comment: Javascript/JQuery does not do it that way. Perhaps it usually is best practice to have unique values, but in this case, on postback I grab via text, and allow javascript to do something based on whether true or false is a value when the user is filling out the form.

Ultimately why would asp.net have that behaviour? the selected index should be the one that is selected, nomatter what the values are.

Comment: You can add the ListItem, and then add some attribute to them, and access them through jQuery or Javascript.

Comment: The reason is basically that there are two parts to the form, depending on which is selected, that part is required or not. That's the javascript part.